# Show error message when <select> is empty / no selection or default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to get an error message when select is set to default and nothing is selected. For input fields the code works, but I can't figure out where I'm wrong for the select part. Anyone help me?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/1sLtk2a7/2/

```js
//Error Msg for input field
function validateForm() {
  let x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
alert("Name must be filled out");
return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" form="myForm">
<select id="select-sex" form="myForm" name="radios"> 
 <option id="opt-default" form="myForm" selected>Select...</option>
 <option id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male" form="myForm">Uomo</option>
 <option id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female" form="myForm">Donna</option>
</select>


<button onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#select-sex').value == 'Select...'` will retrn true if its not filled out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just repeat your logic you used on the `input` for the `select`:

```js
//Error Msg for input field
function validateForm() {
  let x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  let y = document.forms["myForm"]["radios"].value;
  if (y == "Select...") {
    alert("Select must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" form="myForm">
<select id="select-sex" form="myForm" name="radios">
  <option id="opt-default" form="myForm" selected>Select...</option>
  <option id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male" form="myForm">Uomo</option>
  <option id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female" form="myForm">Donna</option>
</select>


<button onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
</form>
```

However, a much more scalable solution is to add the `required` field to your inputs, then use `checkValidity()`:

```js
function validateForm(){
  const isValid = myForm.checkValidity();
  if(!isValid){
    alert("Please fill all fields");
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="fname" form="myForm" required>
  <select id="select-sex" form="myForm" name="radios" required>
    <option id="opt-default" value="" form="myForm" selected disabled>Select...</option>
    <option id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male" form="myForm">Uomo</option>
    <option id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female" form="myForm">Donna</option>
  </select>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to correctly implement the function inside the code of my project. I used checkvalidity and required as it seemed more appropriate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

An `<option>` without a `value=` defaults to the text value of that option. ie

```
<option>Seleziona</option>
```

is the same as

```
<option value="Seleziona">Seleziona</option>
```

So you either need to check for "Seleziona" or you need to give it a value.

```
<option value="">Seleziona</option>
```

Note: *Seleziona* comes from OPs fiddle

Updated snippet:

```js
//Error Msg for input field
function validateForm() {
  let name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  let gender = document.forms["myForm"]["radios"].value;
  if (name == "" || gender == "") {
    alert("Name and gender must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" form="myForm">
<select id="select-sex" form="myForm" name="radios">
  <option id="opt-default" form="myForm" value="" selected>Seleziona</option>
  <option id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male" form="myForm">Uomo</option>
  <option id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female" form="myForm">Donna</option>
</select>


<button onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable tip, everything works fine. However I chose a solution that @Spectric suggested as I found it more appropriate for my project. Thanks again.